# Variables con doble comilla obligatorio

Tags: php, string, template-strings

Intento construir un panel de administrador (formulario) en el cual ingreso contenido, y con el envío combino el contenido y la plantilla creando una nueva página. La plantilla utiliza `<?=$variable?>` en donde va contenido, y la pagina del contenido contiene varias `$variable="string"` y un `required "template.php"` al final.

El código del panel es este, que por ahora estoy probando con el título:

```
<form method="post" >
    <input name="title" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $create = fopen("page1.php","a+");
            fwrite($create, "<?php ".'$head='.'"$_REQUEST["title"]"'."; require 'template.php'; ?>");
            fclose($create);
        }
    ?>
```

`$head` es la variable para el título en la pagina que se va a crear. Cuando se ejecuta el código, debe crear un archivo php que contenga este otro código:

```
<?php
$head="contenido de título";
require 'template.php';
?>"
```

Es necesario que el valor de las variables del archivo generado tengan doble comilla y no otro tipo de comilla, de lo contrario la importación de la plantilla falla ya que dentro del contenido hay comillas simples. Pero cuando ejecuto el código generador, sale así:

```
<?php
$head="$_REQUEST["title"]";
require 'template.php';
?>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para generar el codigo con el valor de la variable `$_REQUEST["title"]` pero con doble comilla? porque otras soluciones en las que sí me sale el valor de la variable, me da comilla simple, cosa que no quiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con cambiar un poco la línea problemática: colocaremos las comillas dobles `"` **dentro** de las comillas simples `'`:

```
fwrite( $create, "<?php ".'$head="' . $_REQUEST["title"] . '"' . "; require 'template.php'; ?>" );
```